# Two queries in one

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I merge these 2 queries? I'm having a rough time writing this query.

1)

```
SELECT question_id, name, question_text FROM questions 
 WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-99.254512 19.347091)',
 4326)::geography, 1000)::geometry, the_geom)
```

2)

```
select q.question_id, COUNT(qa.question_id) as answer_count
from    questions q
left join question_answers qa
on qa.question_id = q.question_id
group by q.question_id
```

(I'm a complete noob in SQL.)

Is there any way to do this:

```
SELECT 
(COUNT(qa.question_id) as answer_count
from    questions q
left join question_answers qa
on qa.question_id = q.question_id
group by q.question_id),

question_id, name, question_text FROM questions 
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-99.254512 19.347091)',
4326)::geography, 1000)::geometry, the_geom)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use derived tables joined by `question_id` as both queries share `questions` as a table source (adjust `WHERE` clause function to include `t1` table alias on any column fields):

```
SELECT t1.question_id, t1.name, t1.question_text, t2.answer_count    
FROM    
    (SELECT question_id, name, question_text 
     FROM questions 
     WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-99.254512 19.347091)',
           4326)::geography, 1000)::geometry, the_geom)) AS t1    
INNER JOIN    
    (SELECT q.question_id, COUNT(qa.question_id) as answer_count
     FROM  questions q
     LEFT JOIN question_answers qa 
     ON qa.question_id = q.question_id
     GROUP BY q.question_id) AS t2    
ON t1.question_id = t2.question_id
```

Alternatively, you could go your suggested route with aggregate subquery, matching inner and outer queries again by `question_id` (as above adjust `WHERE` clause function to include `main` table alias on any column fields):

```
SELECT main.question_id, main.name, main.question_text,
       (SELECT COUNT(qa.question_id)
        FROM  questions q
        LEFT JOIN question_answers qa 
        ON qa.question_id = q.question_id
        WHERE q.question_id = main.question_id
        GROUP BY q.question_id) as answer_count 
FROM questions AS main
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-99.254512 19.347091)',
       4326)::geography, 1000)::geometry, the_geom)
```

Comment: thanks =) it worked. I used the second one. worked just fine ==)

Answer (score 2):

This can be simplified:

```
select q.question_id, COUNT(qa.question_id) as answer_count
from    questions q
left join question_answers qa
on qa.question_id = q.question_id
group by q.question_id
```

to:

```
select qa.question_id, COUNT(qa.question_id) as answer_count
from    question_answers qa
group by qa.question_id
```

And then it MIGHT be added into the other query this way

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.name, q.question_text, COALESCE(qac.answer_count,0) as answer_count
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN (
            select qa.question_id, COUNT(qa.question_id) as answer_count
            from question_answers qa
            group by qa.question_id
          ) qac on q.question_id = qac.question_id
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-99.254512 19.347091)',
 4326)::geography, 1000)::geometry, the_geom)
```